# Solving $y''+2y'+2y=e^{-x}\sin(x)$ using undetermined coefficients.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I would like to know whether I have correctly solved the following differential equation since the book gives a different answer than I did. 
$$y''+2y'+2y=e^{-x}\sin(x)$$
We guess the solution has the form of, $e^{rt}[A \cos(kt)+B \sin(kt)]$.

First we try
$e^{-t}[A\cdot \cos(t) + B \cdot \sin(t)]$, then 
$$y'=-e^{-t}[A \cos(t) + B  \sin(t)]+e^{-t}[-A\sin(t) + B \cos(t)] $$
and 
$$y''=e^{-t}[A \cos(t) + B  \sin(t)]  + e^{-t}[-A\cos(t) - B  \sin(t)].$$
We get the form: 
$$e^{-t}\big[(A-A-2A+2B+2A)\cos(t)+(B-B-2B-2A+2B)\sin(t)\big] \\=e^{-t}(2B \cos(t) - 2A \sin(t))$$

hence $B=0 $ and $A=-\frac{1}{2}$  and thus 
$$y_{p}=e^{-t}(-\frac{1}{2}\cos(t)).$$

since $y_{h}=e^{-t}(A\cos(t)+B  \sin(t))$ the solution to the differential equation is

$$y_{s}=e^{-t}[A \cos(t)+B \sin(t) - \frac{1}{2} \cos(t)].$$

---

However my book get the solution;

$$y_{s}=-\frac{1}{2} t e^{-t}\cos(t)+e^{-t}(A \cos(t) +B \sin(t)).$$

So somehow they included $x$ in their initial guess, can you explain why?

Comment: I did the product rule wrong. Sloppy... This should have told me to use a different form and hence include a variable in our guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make for the particular solution the ansatz $$y_P=Ae^{-x}x\cos(x)$$

Comment: @dr-sonnhard-graubner Can you explain why you add the x to it?

Comment: Since the solution is given by $$C_2e^{-x}\cos(x)+C_1e^{-x}\sin(x)$$